# Only one side of my headphones works

Tags: audio, arch-linux, headphones, alsa, pulse-audio

The distro I'm using is Arch, and my headphones are Sony's WH-H910N model. These headphones are connected by a jack rather than using bluetooth, and they work properly with or without this jack on multiple other machines, so that rules out both a hardware issue, and an issue with the jack.

I checked the settings in PulseAudio, and saw the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsxEm.jpg

Also, more settings here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFBUy.jpg

I also checked alsamixer, and found something peculiar. There is only one output, seemingly, for my headphones.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVLfv.jpg

So how could I even go about fixing this? Do I need to install some drivers, alter certain configs, reboot my machine? I'm at a loss on this one.

Comment: Have you tried any other sets of plug-in headphones using the same configuration?

Comment: Do your headphones have a 3 or 4 ring connector?